# How to pass the id from each row of a loop table using jquery when edit button is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table that displays all the data from my database and I've added a new column for edit button on each row so that this would update the data from my database when the user click a certain button he wants to update.

I have this code to loop through the data and display in a tabular format in my page:

```
<!--############## TABLE HEADER ##############-->
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Dummy ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>NCA Balances</th>
    <th>Account</th>
    <!-- Update Button on each row -->
    <th style="text-align:center;">Update</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!--##########################################-->

<!--############# TABLE CONTENT ##############-->
<tbody>
<?php
    $s1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nca_totals");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s4)) {
        $db_id      = $row['total_id'];
        $db_date    = $row['nca_date'];
        $db_balance = $row['nca_total'];
        $db_account = $row['account_type'];
?>

<tr>
    <!-- Input fields to be hidden just to get the ID value -->
    <td><input type="text" id="total_id" value="<?php echo $db_id ?>"></td>

    <td><?php echo $db_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format($db_balance,2) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db_account ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" id="btn-update">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>  
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
<!--##########################################-->
```

I want to use Ajax in jQuery so that when the user click the button update, the page does not have to reload. But first, I want to confirm that I get exactly the ID on each row and pass it to my jquery function like this:

**update_nca.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get the values
    $("#btn-update").click(function(){
        var total_id = $("#total_id").val();
        alert(total_id);
    });
});
```

When I click the first button on the first row, It gets the ID from my table. But on the next row as well as the other row, no ID has been pass into my jquery. It doesn't get any value from my dummy textbox. Please help me improve my codes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are sharing the same ID to multiple inputs which makes a problem! I think you better use a class instead or remove it.

```
<tr>
    <!-- Input fields to be hidden just to get the ID value -->
    <td><input type="text" class="total_id" value="<?php echo $db_id ?>"></td>

    <td><?php echo $db_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format($db_balance,2) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db_account ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn-update">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>



$(".btn-update").click(function(){
    var total_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.total_id').val();
        alert(total_id);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can set up an incemental ID but you are much encouraged to use class. That is what it's used for.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique in any HTML document. You can use classes to represent the identity. Change `id="total_id"` to `class="total_id"`. And `id="btn-update"` to `class="btn-update"`.

Then, use this code to get the value from the total-id input.

```
$(".btn-update").click(function(){
    var total_id = $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_id").val();
    alert(total_id);
});
```

BTW way, `$(this)` represented the element that's taking the event, in this case the `update button`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass the `db_id` value to a `data-` attribute, perhaps named `data-db-id`.  Since each `<tr>` represents a record, place the `data-db-id` attribute on each `<tr>` element.  Then with jQuery, retrieve the value of the `data-` attribute with the [`.data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/): `var id = $(this).data('db-id')`.  See complete example below:

```
<?php
    $s1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nca_totals");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s4)) {
        $db_id      = $row['total_id'];
        $db_date    = $row['nca_date'];
        $db_balance = $row['nca_total'];
        $db_account = $row['account_type'];
?>

<tr data-db-id="<?= $db_id ?>">
    <td><?= $db_date ?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($db_balance,2) ?></td>
    <td><?= $db_account ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <button class="btn-update">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>  
<?php } ?>
</tbody>

<script>
  $('table').on('click', '.btn-update', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('db-id');
    // do something with the id....
  });
</script>
```

Note a few changes:

1. This example uses the [short PHP echo syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (`<?= $foo ?>`).
2. Event delegation is used here.  [Read more here.](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
3. As others have already said, keep your `id` attribute values unique. (i.e., switch `id="btn_update"` in your loop to `class="btn_update")